# In QED, can a photon travelling in free space experience change in its frequency?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, frequency, path-integral

If we want to find the probability amplitude of a photon to travel from point A to B, do we need to consider the amplitude that its frequency may change in the path?

Also, is it possible to detect the frequency of the photon at points A and B without disturbing the experiment, such that we only need to worry about the shift in frequency in the middle?

If so, can we still use the equation $K\propto e^{i\frac{2\pi L}{\lambda } }$ for the kernel of the motion, and integrate over all the intermediate changes in $\lambda$ to get the final amplitude?

Here, $L$ is the length of the path.

Comment: I assume by amplitude you mean the probability amplitude. But when you say "without disturbing the experiment", do you mean without interacting with the photon? While you can generate a photon at a desired frequency with reasonable precision, you can't measure the frequency of an already existing photon at point A without interacting with it. There is no such thing as a passive measurement on that scale

Comment: By measuring, I mean generating electron with precision. So it can be done, then. Also, at point B, any sensitive detector should be able to determine the energy of the incident photon. So, it seems we can determine the frequency at points A and B, without desturbing the probability amplitude of the motion between the points.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the path integral approach to quantum mechanics, the photon is to be assumed to have a constant frequency throughout its path. It can be assumed to take whatever path it likes, moving at the speed of light (this one appears to be only an approximation for large distances), and it can also start it's journey at any time, (which means that if a detector received a photon at a particular instance from a source some distance away from it, and if there is no way of telling when exactly the photon left from the source to complete it's journey towards the detector, then amplitude for all possibilities of the photon leaving the source at different times has to be included).

A small detail which needs to be added here is that if we are considering all the possibilities of time  for the photon to leave the source, then the initial imaginary phase of all the photons will be the same. This is necessary, and corresponds to the assumption that the source is a coherent source of monochromatic light.

This answer is based on Feynman's book [QED](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED:_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter). If there is some error, kindly point it out.